# Bootstrap grid columns overlapping

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, overlap

I'm trying to make a connect 4 board with bootstrap, but when i add a circle to a new column it overlaps with the circle to its left.

This is my html code (it's an example, there should be 7 columns):

```
<div class="container">

  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-offset-2 col-md-1">
      <a href="#"><div></div></a>
      <a href="#"><div></div></a>
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-1">
      <a href="#"><div></div></a>
      <a href="#"><div></div></a>
    </div>

</div>
```

And this is my css:

```
.container{
text-align: center;
}
a div{
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  background-color: #858585;
  border: 4px solid black;
  border-radius: 100%;
  margin-bottom: 2px;
}
```

This is the output:

[circles overlapping](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fYGIu.png)

Is it because of the size of the circles?

Comment: Your question isnt clear enough. Maybe you should make an executable example with stackoverflow tool or jsfiddle

Comment: @Kiwad Thank you, i've added a picture.

Answer (score 1):

Your circles are overlapping because you're not giving them mkore with than their Bootstrap container. You've got a hard-coded with of `100px`, but very narrow column declarations (at `col-md-1`).

Bootstrap columns always add up to 12. You have a total of four -- two `md` declarations, plus 2 from `offset`. The remaining 8 columns are unoccupied. This means that your content will be squished to the left.

Assuming you want seven columns (with the first one offset), you're probably looking for a structure similar to this:

```
<div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-offset-2 col-md-1"></div>
    <div class="col-md-1"></div>
    <div class="col-md-2"></div>
    <div class="col-md-2"></div>
    <div class="col-md-2"></div>
    <div class="col-md-1"></div>
    <div class="col-md-1"></div>
</div>
```

The above `col-md--` declarations all add to 12, and thus occupy the fully width. Note that you can use **any** combination of widths to sum up to 12 columns -- 3 fours, 4 threes, 6 twos, etc.

To ensure that your circles never esacpe their bounds (and thus overlap), you need to set a `max-width` of 100%:

```
a div{
  max-width: 100%;
}
```

Alternatively, if you only want **two** columns (as illustrated in your image), you can give them a wider column width. Simply divide (12 - [offset]) by the number of columns you would like, and that's the specification that you should use.

In this case, that's `5`, as we subtract the offset of `2` from `12`, and then divide the `10` by `2`, giving us `5`:

```
<div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-offset-2 col-md-5"></div>
    <div class="col-md-5"></div>
</div>
```

Also, note that you missed the closing `</div>` for `<div class="row">` :)

Hope this helps! :)

Comment: Thank you for your detailed answer! First, yes, you are right about that missing </div>, but it was an accident when i was pasting the code here, i have that closing tag in the actual file:)
About your solution, the problem is that the circles overlap, and it seems it's because of the size i'm giving to them, if i change the height and weight to 80px it works fine ):
Do you have any idea about how to do this without bootstrap?

Comment: No problem. The overlap is caused because of the circles overlapping their parents, and the parent width is defined by Bootstrap. If you go with my first solution, you need to make your circles smaller, or define a `max-width` of `100%`. If you go with my second solution, the two circles will automatically be far apart. Also, at no point in your question did you mention that you would like a solution that solves the problem **without** Bootstrap. Considering you're already using it, you might as well continue to - Bootstrap is a great framework if used correctly. Just remember the rule of 12s.

Comment: Yes! exactly. I did it with smaller circles for now, it's an exercise for a udemy course :) But i would like to do it myself first. The thing is that in the example of the course the circles looks bigger, and i don't know if the instructor used bootstrap or no for it but that's the only way i can imagine to do it by now.
Anyway, i'll do it with smaller circles and then i can check the solutions.
Thank you!
What do you mean with the rule of 12s btw? 12 cols?

Answer (score 0):

Since bootstrap columns are flexible (in % and not in px) you should set a maximum value in percentage.

```
a div{
  width: 200px;
  height: 200px;
  max-width: 100%;
  background-color: #858585;
  border: 4px solid black;
  border-radius: 100%;
  margin-bottom: 2px;
}
```

Comment: Thank you for your help, in theory it solves the problem, but it makes the -not- circles too long and thin.

Comment: any idea for doing this without bootstrap?